# Stanford NER not tagging date and time

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am using Stanford NER tagger in python. It is not tagging dates and time. Rather returns O on every word.
My sentence was:

"What sum of money will earn an interest of $ 162 in 3 years at the rate of 12% per annum"

The result I got after tagging was-

```
[('What', 'O'), ('sum', 'O'), ('of', 'O'), ('money', 'O'), ('will', 'O'), ('earn', 'O'), ('an', 'O'), ('interest', 'O'), ('of', 'O'), ('$', 'O'), ('162', 'O'), ('in', 'O'), ('3', 'O'), ('years', 'O'), ('at', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('rate', 'O'), ('of', 'O'), ('12%', 'O'), ('per', 'O'), ('annum', 'O')]
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download and install Stanford NLP Group's Python library `stanza` .

   GitHub: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza
2. With Stanford CoreNLP 3.7.0, start a server:

   command: `java -Xmx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000`

   Stanford CoreNLP 3.7.0: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

   (Note: make sure CLASSPATH contains all of the jars in the download folder)
3. Issue a request to the Java Stanford CoreNLP server started in Step 2:

   ```
   from stanza.nlp.corenlp import CoreNLPClient

   client = CoreNLPClient(server='http://localhost:9000', default_annotators=['ssplit', 'tokenize', 'lemma', 'pos', 'ner'])

   annotated = client.annotate("..text to annotate...")

   for sentence in annotated.sentences:
     print "---"
     print sentence.tokens
     print sentence.ner_tags
   ```

   We are working on having the Python library handle starting and stopping the server for Stanford CoreNLP 3.8.0.